# how to extract text(ONLY) from the syncfusion documentEditor using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, blob, syncfusion

I am using angular and I would like to extract the text from documentEditor and save it to a field in my DB . I am using the SaveAsBlob that is mentioned in the documentation. please note the txt saveAsBlob method is being called after another saveAsBlob method which is successfully saving a DOCX .

**Error**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at TextExport.writeTable (ej2-documenteditor.es5.js:114144:40)
    at TextExport.writeBody (ej2-documenteditor.es5.js:114120:22)
    at TextExport.writeHeaderFooter (ej2-documenteditor.es5.js:114169:18)
    at TextExport.writeHeadersFooters (ej2-documenteditor.es5.js:114161:14)
    at TextExport.writeInternal (ej2-documenteditor.es5.js:114104:18)
    at TextExport.saveAsBlob (ej2-documenteditor.es5.js:114066:14)
    at ej2-documenteditor.es5.js:119255:48
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:1411:21)
    at DocumentEditor.saveAsBlob (ej2-documenteditor.es5.js:119250:16)
    at TestWritingAnswertemplateComponent.saveToTrackingTable (test-writing-answertemplate.component.ts:965:35
```

**HTML**

```
<ejs-documenteditorcontainer
  [serviceUrl]='"https://ej2services.syncfusion.com/production/web- 
  services/api/documenteditor/"'
  style="display:block"
  (contentChange)="onContentChange()"
  height="800" width="100%"
  #documentEditor
  [enableToolbar]=true
  [isReadOnly]=false
  [enableEditor]=true >
</ejs-documenteditorcontainer>
```

**TS**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  setInterval(() => {
    // This method is successfully saving the DOCX using saveAsBlob method
    this.saveTestAnswerDoc();
    this.saveToTrackingTable();
  }, 30000);
}

public saveToTrackingTable() {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  this.container.documentEditor.enableTextExport = true;

  this.container.documentEditor.saveAsBlob('Txt').then((exportedDocument: Blob) => {
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      this.readerResult = reader.result.toString();
      console.log(reader.result.toString());
      this.saveTrackingAnswersLocal(reader.result.toString());
    };

    reader.readAsText(exportedDocument);

    this.container.documentEditor.saveAsBlob('Txt').then((exportedDocument: Blob) => {
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        this.readerResult = reader.result.toString();
        console.log(reader.result.toString());
        this.saveTrackingAnswersLocal(reader.result.toString());
      };

      reader.readAsText(exportedDocument);
    });
  });

  console.log(this.readerResult);

  if (!this.readerResult) {
    console.log("retreiving tracking text.....");
    //this.sendStudentAnswerTextData();
  }

  var stud: StudentTestAnswer;

  stud = {
    id: this.testId,
    studentId: this.studentId,
    accomodation: true,
    fullScreenClosed: false,
    answerText: this.readerResult,
    keyPress: false,
    offline: false,
    leftExamArea: false,
    fileName: "FileName",
    timeRemaining: "00:00",
    testId: this.testId,
  };

  this.studentTestWriteService.saveAnswersInterval(stud).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });

  //this.contentChanged = false;

  console.log("finished saving");
}
```

Comment: The code you provided, has two sequential calls to saveAsBlob for TXT. It's important to note that the second call might interfere with the first one. You should try to remove the redundant call and focus on the first call to see if it resolves the issue.